# log4net : Custom loglevel

Tags: log4net

Can I know how to create custom loglevel ? it will be great provided with a sample example. I have seen many examples for trace and verbose, but if I want other those how to create.

Thanks in Advance

Regards,

Abhinay

Answer (score 2):

log4net internally defines already the following levels:

Emergency, Fatal, Alert, Critical, Severe, Error, Warn, Notice, Info, Debug, Fine, Trace, Finer, Verbose, Finest

If these are enough then you can use them as you would use for instance the Verbose level.